# Getting result from select query with dbt jinja

Tags: python, sql, jinja2, dbt, duckdb

So I'm working with a duckdb database connected with dbt. Now I can execute my query and it can complete succesfully now the problem that I face is that I want to get the result from this query.
My sql file looks like the following.

```
{%- call statement('all', fetch_result=True) -%}

select * from {{ source("energy_sellers", "energy") }}

{%- endcall -%}

{%- set all = load_result('all') -%}
```

But this returns the following error

```
11:31:59  Running with dbt=1.4.5
11:32:00  Found 1 model, 16 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 409 macros, 0 operations, 0 seed files, 1 source, 0 exposures, 0 metrics
11:32:01
11:32:01  1 of 1 START sql table model energy_sellers.energy_sellers ..................... [RUN]
11:32:01  1 of 1 ERROR creating sql table model energy_sellers.energy_sellers ............ [ERROR in 0.30s]
11:32:01
11:32:01  Finished running 1 table model in 0 hours 0 minutes and 1.34 seconds (1.34s).
11:32:01
11:32:01  Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:
11:32:01
11:32:01  Runtime Error in model energy_sellers (models\example\energy_sellers.sql)
11:32:01    Parser Error: syntax error at or near ")"
11:32:01    LINE 10:     );
11:32:01                 ^
11:32:01
11:32:01  Done. PASS=0 WARN=0 ERROR=1 SKIP=0 TOTAL=1
```

The thing is my file has 7 lines, yet it says there is an error on line 10.
My file is located in `models/example/energy_sellers.sql`
Any help is greatly appreciated.

But when my file looks like this it doesn't produce an error.

```
select * from {{ source("energy_sellers", "energy") }}
```

Then I get this as output

```
12:49:03  Running with dbt=1.4.5
12:49:05  Found 1 model, 16 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 409 macros, 0 operations, 0 seed files, 1 source, 0 exposures, 0 metrics
12:49:05  
12:49:06  Concurrency: 1 threads (target='dev')
12:49:06  
12:49:06  1 of 1 START sql table model energy_sellers.energy_sellers ..................... [RUN]
12:49:08  1 of 1 OK created sql table model energy_sellers.energy_sellers ................ [OK in 1.56s]
12:49:08  
12:49:08  Finished running 1 table model in 0 hours 0 minutes and 3.78 seconds (3.78s).
12:49:08  
12:49:08  Completed successfully
12:49:08  
12:49:08  Done. PASS=1 WARN=0 ERROR=0 SKIP=0 TOTAL=1
```

It is a table btw.

Comment: And there’s no error when you try and call the source model separately to your call statement? Is it a table or ephemeral or view?

Comment: I updated the post hopefully it is the information you needed.

Answer (score 0):

The line number from the error message is coming from after the DBT compiles and runs your model. You can see the results under `target/run/<project_name>/models/example/energey_sellers.sql`

What you will find when you open that model is basically something like this

```
 create or replace   view <DB>.<SCHEMA>.energy_sellers
  
   as (
    
  );
```

The reason you're getting the error is because your model isn't outputting anything. All your model is doing is executing a query *at compile time* and then storing the results in a variable called `all`. There is no SQL being produced, which results in DBT generating the empty create statement above.

When you remove the `call statement`, your compiled version of the model will be

```
 create or replace   view <DB>.<SCHEMA>.energy_sellers
  
   as (
    select * from <DB>.energy_sellers.energy
  );
```

which is why that version works. If you want to see the results, you can add `{% do log(all['data']) %}`. This will output the results to your console, but the model will still fail until you actually produce valid SQL.