# dbt run_query macro from dbt-utils throws syntax error

Tags: dbt, dbt-utils

When I follow the trivial example from the dbt-utils website: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query

```
-- models/foo.sql
{% if execute %}

    {% set results = run_query('select 1 as id') %}
    {% do results.print_table() %}

{% endif %}
```

I get the syntax error:

```
Database Error in model testcard_id_audit (models/audit/foo.sql)
  syntax error at or near ")"
  LINE 13:   );
```

I actually get this with every query I try to run.

dbt version:

```
dbt --version                                                                                                                                              

Core:
  - installed: 1.7.10
  - latest:    1.7.10 - Up to date!

Plugins:
  - postgres: 1.7.10 - Up to date!
```

dbt-utils:

```
- package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils
  version: 0.9.6
```

Comment: What does your `foo.sql` model look like? You need to do something with the macro in order for it be a valid DBT model. If all your model is doing is calling the macro, then it's not producing a valid SQL statement for inserting data into your destination table.

Comment: If you want to debug what is happening and see the sql executed, i recommend the --debug flag when you execute your dbt run

Comment: @AdamKipnis, the trivial example is foo.sql. I added it as a comment

Comment: You're creating an empty model. Your Jinja for running a query is executed at compile time and then the results are used at run time to generate the SQL for your table. Your problem is the same as the one asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898107/getting-result-from-select-query-with-dbt-jinja/75901104#75901104